# Internal Error - Trying to install Valve's Steam client via Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 12.04, software-center, dpkg, steam

Valve's steam client is now Open to all said a link and so I decided to install Steam Client on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine to try it out.

I downloaded the deb file from this [page](http://store.steampowered.com/about/).

Once after the download is completed and I double-clicked to install it and as expected Ubuntu software Centre is launched but with error as stated below:

> Internal Error "The file /home/pras/Downloads/steam_latest.deb can't be opened".

Even I tried to install it via

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

which also throws errors

```
pras@Tuxbox:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb 
[sudo] password for pras: 
(Reading database ... 408406 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking steam (from steam_latest.deb) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): short read on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing steam_latest.deb (--install):
 short read on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_ubuntu12_32.tar.xz'
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam_latest.deb
```

So how should I install it?

Comment: maybe the downloaded file is just corrupt? Try download a fresh copy and install it again.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing out it. There seems to be a problem with their server. The file is around 5 MB while the download get interrupted at random places on every download I try again and again. For 1st time it stopped at 35% and next time 62% and something like that. So the problem is due to Incomplete download of the file.

Comment: use wget as stated by nighthawk. `wget -c http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb`. If the download stops at the middle wget will be able to continue it.

Comment: There's an alternative method [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/905876/225694)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same problem.

To get around it I used 'wget' in a terminal to download the file.

When the interruption happened 'wget' just reconnected and continued to download the file.

I used the following command

wget http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb

Comment: +1 Using wget to download worked better for me than using a web browser.  Also note that using the dpkg command instead of trying to open the .DEB with the software center worked better too.

Comment: I used Flareget to get the work done. Anyway thanks to Salem, nighthawk-uk and Ed Manet