# Steam not installing on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation, software-center, steam

I have tried a couple of different methods of installing Steam.

If I install "Steam Installer" by searching for Steam in the software centre, and click launch, nothing happens.

If I try to install it using the command line, using [these](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux) instructions, when I enter "gdebi steam.deb" it outputs "gdebi error, file not found: steam.deb".

If I try to download Steam directly from Valve [here](http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb), it opens the software centre, and as with installing from the installer in my first method, nothing happens when I click install.

Comment: Download steam.deb, put it in home folder (folder where folders Documents, Downloads Pictures are...), run sudo dpkg -i steam.deb.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. [Enable the Universe Repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)
2. Install gdebi: `sudo apt-get install gdebi`
3. Download Steam [here](http://store.steampowered.com/about/)
4. When prompted select "Other" and then select "GDebi" as the installer as shown below:

   [image: gdebi]
5. Click "Install Package", and when you see the image below click "Start Steam" to complete the installation.

   [image: StartSteam]
6. Enjoy!

**Edit:** For some reason I had to run `~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam` to get it to launch and update the first time. Since then it launches normally.

Comment: Thanks. Can I uninstall the default Ubuntu Software?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. https://askubuntu.com/q/133456/263726

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04.  That last edit worked!! YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!

Comment: You don't need to install gdebi. The default deb installer (double click on the deb file) in ubuntu just works fine.

Comment: @firepol I'm glad that worked (for you). Perhaps you would be so kind as to write a detailed  answer so that others can benefit from your experience.

Comment: @ElderGeek no need for more details than what I just wrote. It's basically your answer without step 2. Double click the deb file and follow what the next screens tell you (usually click on _next_ or _ok_). As easy as that.

Comment: @firepol I assume by the "default deb installer" you mean gnome-software? Back when this answer was written it was pretty [buggy.](https://askubuntu.com/a/783943/225694) It's good to know that the current version is functional.